# Toolbar not showing in overridden catalog list block

Tags: magento2, plugin

I have this in my `di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock">
    <plugin name="easymart_inject" type="NameSpace\Module\Plugin\CategoryPlugin" />    
</type>
```

And my `CategoryPlugin.php`

```
<?php
namespace NameSpace\Module\Plugin;

class CategoryPlugin
{

    protected $_request;
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ){
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
    }

    public function aftertoHtml(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock $block, $result){

        if($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_category_view'){
            $category = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_category');
            if($category && $category->getId()==5 && $block->getNameInLayout() == 'category.products.list'){
                $bl = $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\NameSpace\Module\Block\Band::class);

                return $bl->toHtml();
            }
        }    
        return $result;
    }
```

And my `Band.php` class

```
<?php
namespace NamsSpace\Module\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Config;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;
use Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice;
use Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\BasePrice;
use Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\ConfiguredRegularPrice;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\Element;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render;
use Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data;


class Band extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{
    protected $_productFactory;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $baseAmount;
    protected $priceInterface;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        PostHelper $postDataHelper,
        Resolver $layerResolver,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        Data $urlHelper,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Amount\BaseFactory $baseAmount,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\AbstractPriceFactory $priceInterface,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->baseAmount = $baseAmount;
        $this->priceInterface = $priceInterface;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $postDataHelper,
            $layerResolver,
            $categoryRepository,
            $urlHelper,
            $data
        );
        $this->setTemplate('NameSpace_Module::band.phtml');
    }
}
?>
```

Now, in my `band.phtml` all the products for that category is loaded, but no toolbar is printing.

My `band.phtml`

```
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
//echo "SIZE: ".$_productCollection->getSize()."<br>"; //prints correct size
```

**But it never shows toolbar.** Below code in `band.phtml` has no effect at all. Any suggestions?

```
<?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('product_list_toolbar') ?>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('toolbar') ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so I had to add `toolbar` again.

```
$block->getLayout()->getBlock('product_list_toolbar');
$bl->setChild('toolbar', $orgListBlock);
```

So, full function:

```
public function aftertoHtml(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock $block, $result){

    if($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_category_view'){
        $category = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_category');
        if($category && $category->getId()==5 && $block->getNameInLayout() == 'category.products.list'){
            $bl = $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\NameSpace\Module\Block\Band::class, 'my_block');

            $toolbar = $block->getLayout()->getBlock('product_list_toolbar');
            $bl->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);

            $result = $bl->toHtml();
        }
    }    
    return $result;
}
```

I hope this helps someone.